# Perform multiple functions on each row of matrix and append results to new dataframe

Tags: r, matrix

I have a  matrix. Example data:

```
 matrix<- matrix(sample(1:10), nrow= 10,ncol=20)
```

NOTE: In my real matrix the row names are plot numbers which are important to keep associated with values for that row.

I want to perform a variety of functions (diversity functions from the vegan package) on  each row of the matrix. The functions include:

```
library(vegan)
div1<- diversity(matrix, index="shannon")
div2<- diversity(matrix, index="simpson")
div3<- exp(diversity(matrix,index="shannon"))
div4<- 1/(1-diversity(matrix,index="simpson"))
spec.num<- specnumber(matrix)
```

The output should be a data frame. Each column of this dataframe represents the unique diversity index.  The output would look like:

```
Rownames     div1        div2    div3  div4     spec.num   
  Plot1     2.995732    0.95    20     20         20
  Plot34    2.995732    0.95    20     20         20
  Plot56    2.995732    0.95    20     20         20
  Plot60    2.995732    0.95    20     20         20
```

Note: For my real data the matrix rows have unique values for each column, they will not be repeated as my example indicates. Thus, the output for div3,div4, spec number will not necessarily be the same values as it shows in this example output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(vegan)

matrix<- matrix(sample(1:10), nrow= 10,ncol=20)
#rownames(matrix) <- paste0("plot", 1:nrow(matrix)) ## this is/was merely an illustration on carrying rownames forward

df <- data.frame(div1=diversity(matrix, index="shannon"), div2=diversity(matrix, index="simpson"), 
      div3=exp(diversity(matrix,index="shannon")), div4=1/(1-diversity(matrix,index="simpson")), spec.nu=specnumber(matrix), row.names = rownames(matrix))
```

Comment: the `rownames` call is not necessary if your matrix already has rownames (this was to illustrate carrying over the rownames). Or if your "rownames" are in column 1 change `row.names = rownames(matrix)` to `row.names = matrix[, 1]`

Comment: Now I am realizing my question was not as complicated as I first asked and your solution is very clean and helpful. The only issue I am running into (and I believe it stems from `1:nrow(matrix)` using the `rownames` function) is that my plot numbers do not go sequentially from 1-100. Some plots I had to remove from the original dataframe so the matrix skips from plot 85 to plot 88, for example. When I use your code on my data it appears to sequentially number the plots, thus reassigning plot numbers. Thus, plot 88 is  renumbered as plot 86, when it needs to remain plot 88.

Comment: Please see my edit. you do not need the `rownames(matrix) <- paste0("plot", 1:nrow(matrix))` so I have commented it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to column bind your results?

```
# if you set your sampling range to be 1:1000 these diversity values are no longer constant
mtx <- matrix(sample(1:1000), nrow= 10,ncol=20) # I like to avoid like names
#install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)
div1<- diversity(mtx, index="shannon")
div2<- diversity(mtx, index="simpson")
div3<- exp(diversity(mtx,index="shannon"))
div4<- 1/(1-diversity(mtx,index="simpson"))
spec.num<- specnumber(mtx) 
cbind(div1, div2, div3, div4, spec.num) # cbinding equal length vectors into a data.frame/matrix 
#cbind.data.frame()
```